# C reverse function isn't working for length of 8 or 9 but works for others?

Tags: c, string

Hi i've made a function in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int reverse(char* str){
    int len = strlen(str);
    char tempp[len];
    int temp = 0;
    int x = len-1;
    for (int temp = 0; temp < len; temp++){
        tempp[temp] = str[x-temp];
    }
    printf("%s", tempp);
    return 0;
    }
void main() {
    reverse("helooo");
}
```

which outputs oooleh
but when i input "Mcmaster" or "Helooooo"
it outputs ooooleh,@ or retsamcm,@

i want it to output without the ",@"
thanks

Comment: Are you null-terminating your strings?

Comment: One major issue: You forget that strings in C are really called ***null-terminated** strings*, and that this *null-terminator* is not counted by `strlen`. You still need space for it in your arrays if you want to use them as "strings".

Comment: Hello, can you tell me how to null terminate my strings? or like what part of the code im supposed to change. im very new to C would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: @saxenm2 `char tempp[len];` declares an array of `len` chars, but as stated by other comments, a string is terminated by a null character, therefore you need one more char. This is covered in any C learning material in the chapter dealing with strings.

Comment: I got it thanks everyone! appreciate it!